# Поиск совпадений по двум столбцам в vba

Tags: excel, vba

Подскажите хороший алгоритм поиска совпадений в vba по двум ячейкам из разных столбцов?

Comment: Есть мнение, что ни один VBA-код не отработает быстрее, чем встроенные механизмы программы. Поэтому обычно(!) лучшим вариантом является вызов встроенных функций типа MATCH() или SUMPRODUCT() или VLOOKUP() по объединённой строке

Comment: Ок, спасибо, осталось разобраться с этим встроенными функциями

Answer (score 0):

=ВПР(Patient!N17;DocList!F2:G550;2;ЛОЖЬ)
находит совпадение для ячейки N17 текущего листа, среди элементов первого столбца массива DocList!F2:G550, если найдет показывает ячейку из второго столбца того же массива напротив найденного элемента
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уверены, что именно это нужно было автору? В вопросе - совпадение ячеек, не более. Это может быть простой поиск дублей (СЧЕТЕСЛИ, например)